# GCM HTML5 App with Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, google-cloud-messaging

How can i implement de functionaly on jquery mobile such as the examples in Android.

> I have already made the server in PHP, but now i want to make the registration from my app into GCM service and send it to my server.

Comment: You may need to clarify some things here. What examples? Do you have a PHP server? Also include code that you tried, that always helps :)

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/ I want to do something like this, actually, this is my php server

Comment: This question is very general now needs to be more specific with more detail about what you are trying to do and where you are getting stuck.